# JSP foreach tag for two variables

Tags: jsp-tags

I want to do something like this

```
<c:forEach var="item1" items="List1" var="item2" items="List2">
 <p> ${item1} ${item2}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

One solution is to iterate through both the List, if both are of same size

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="$(fn:length(List1))">
 <p> <%= List1.get(i) %> <%= List2.get(i)%>  //wrong syntax 
</c:forEach>
```

Any idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `varStatus.index` to get the index of the current round and then use it as a lookup for the second list. Mind the length of the `List`s though or it will throw an Exception . Set the `items` with the `List` having maximum of the two.

```
<c:forEach var="element" items="${List1}" varStatus="status">
 <p>
  ${element}
  ${List2[status.index]}
</c:forEach>
```

1. [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_forEach.html).
2. [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: how to access the element at index i ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Array is Frist List, and B is Second List and varStatus.index to get the index of the current round and then use it as a lookup for the second list.
<c:forEach var="Array" items="${A}" varStatus="status">
<c:out value="${A}","${B[status.index]}"}/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?